# How to auto-update table in 'wix' while inserting in a dataset using submit button?

Tags: javascript, velo

I always need to refresh my browser for the changes to be visible. Is there any way we can directly auto update our table when we press submit button?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to accomplish this:

- you can [Refresh your Dataset](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-dataset.Dataset.html#refresh) when the write to the DB is complete
- you can use the [Realtime API](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-realtime.html) to have your table subscribe to updates in the DB